# how can i implement a flashlight cursor to a specific table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can i implement a flashlight cursor that lights the elements inside my table in order to read the paragraphs inside?
my whole background and body of the website is black and already styled, and i am wishing to keep it that way.
how can i make it happen?
my HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Asaf Danan's resume</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,300;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resume.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="stars"></div>
        <div class="twinkling"></div> 
       <div class="clouds"></div>
       <div class="title">
        <h1><b>Asaf Danan</b></h1><br>
        </div>
        <div class="secondarytitle">
            <h2><b><span>a</span><span>web</span><span>developer</span></b></h2>
            </div>
            <table id="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <td class="tabledata"> <p> a beginner web developer that can barely build this website
                            <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem, corrupti <br>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Similique, quasi!
                            asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd </p>
                        </td>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.title h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 860px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;

  /* Stryling the text and giving it gradiant */
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  /* Make sure text is infront of background images */
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

@keyframes move-twink-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 5000px;
  }
}

@keyframes move-clouds-back {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 10000px 0;
  }
}

.stars,
.twinkling,
.clouds {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.stars {
  background: #000 url(stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.twinkling {
  background: transparent url(twinkling.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 1;
  animation: move-twink-back 200s linear infinite;
}

.clouds {
  background: transparent url(clouds.png) repeat top center;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.4;
  animation: move-clouds-back 200s linear infinite;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2 {
  font-size: 63px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  margin-top: 90px;
  margin-left: 705px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Stryling the text and giving it gradiant */
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

  /* Make sure text is infront of background images */
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2 span {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  margin-right: 28px;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(2)::after {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span:nth-child(2)::after {
  content: "";
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.secondarytitle,
h2:hover span {
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 40px #fff, 0 0 80px #fff,
    0 0 120px #fff;
}
table,
tr,
td,
th{
  color: #ffffff;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee, #333);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 6px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
}
td{
top: 400px;
left: 180px;
width: 1200px;
height: 500px;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

would love to get some help, thank you!
P.S: i tried my best looking up for it online, with 0 success.
please be nice and assist me

Comment: Please first correct your code's syntax. A td element can only have a tr element as its parent. Then make your code into a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It makes it much easier for us to give a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Flashlight cursor as in like

```
element:hover {
   /* change style */
}
```

that? or what

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).